# How to detect GPS hardware support in iPhone using horizontal accuracy?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

in my app a user can fetch the coordinates of his/her location by either using GPS or through Forward geo-coding. the thing i want to ask is, how can i detect that the device being used has hadware GPS support using horizontal accuracy values.???
thanking you in anticipation....

Answer (score 0):

Use: https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension